# bash: using "cut -c" on the strings with spaces like " ?.?"

Tags: bash

i just want to get the third char from watingForHDD. Any idea how to do this?

(my idea was to log some data about the used system capacity etc...)

```
#!/bin/bash
x="`top -d 1 -n 1`"
echo "$x"
waitingForHDD=`echo "$x" | head -n3 | tail -n1 | cut -d"," -f9,10`
echo "$waitingForHDD"     #output(with 2 spaces in the beginning):   0,6 wa 
b=`echo "$waitingForHDD" | cut -c3`
echo "$b"      #output(i mean WTF? thats not even in waitingForHDD): B
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of `top` uses formatting: In `0,6 wa`, the `0,6` is in bold. Use batch mode (`-b`) to disable it:

```
$ top -bd 1 -n 1 | head -n3 | tail -n1 | cut -d, -f5 | cut -c3
1
```

(I am on a different locale, so the fields in the first `cut` differ.)

Try `top -d 1 -n 1 | head -n3 | tail -n1 | cut -d, -f5 | less` to see the special characters in action.

All that said, you might be better of using something like `awk` instead of this jumble of `head`s, `tail`s and `cut`s.

Answer (score 0):

As @muru pointed out, the problem is that `top` uses [ANSI escape sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php) to format its output. You can see this by piping through a program like `od` which will let you see non-printing characters. For example, this command prints the "wa" and "hi" fields of the 3rd line of `top`:

```
$ top -d 1 -n 1 | grep ^% | cut -d"," -f5,6
```

The output on my system is:

> **1.0** wa,  **0.0** hi

Let's have a look at the non-printing characters:

```
$ top -d 1 -n 1 | grep ^% | cut -d"," -f5,6 | od -c
0000000 033   (   B 033   [   m 033   [   3   9   ;   4   9   m 033   [
0000020   1   m           1   .   0     033   (   B 033   [   m 033   [
0000040   3   9   ;   4   9   m   w   a   , 033   (   B 033   [   m 033
0000060   [   3   9   ;   4   9   m 033   [   1   m           0   .   0
0000100     033   (   B 033   [   m 033   [   3   9   ;   4   9   m   h
0000120   i  \n
0000122
```

As you can see above, the third character is a `B` and that's what you're getting. So, assuming you want a script that i) prints all of `top`'s output, ii) prints the "wa" and "hi" fields of the 3rd line and iii) prints the digits from the "wa" field, you could do something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

x="$(top -d 1 -n 1)"
echo "$x"
waitingForHDD=$(grep ^% <<<"$x" | cut -d"," -f5,6)
echo "$waitingForHDD"     
b=$(grep -oP '^.*?\K[.\d]+(?= )' <<<"$waitingForHDD" )
echo "$b"
```